# SSO service integration with Shiny Application

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a Shiny Application( R studio) in dashdb, is there a way i can integrate the SSO service to this app.

Shiny Application was built by R studio in dashdb and now I wanted to integrate SSO service to this application, but I don't find a way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If your app is a Node.js or a Java (Liberty) application, you will be able to integrate the SSO Service.

First you need to create an unbound instance of the Single Sign On service. Once that is done, you can bind your app to your service, and configure it to work with the service.

For more information on setting up the SSO Service, see: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted